# Условия проверки значения?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, sql

При добавлении человека в базу, есть галочка чекбокса, если значение равно `1`, то человека выключить (не отображать на сайте), если `0`, соответственно включить. Подскажите как переделать скрипт. Поле в базе с названием `onoroff`. Другими словами хочу присвоить `display:none;`, если значение `onoroff = 1`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var city = $('#cp_id_626 i').text();

    <?php

    if ( strlen(get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'cp_id_298', true))>0 or strlen(get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'cp_street', true))>0 or strlen(get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'cp_id_185', true))>0 or strlen(get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'cp_id_371', true))>0 or strlen(get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'cp_id_446', true))>0 ):

        mysql_set_charset( 'utf8' );
    $sql_select = "SELECT * FROM users";
    $result = mysql_query($sql_select);

    $tmp = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'cp_id_626', true);
    $i = '';
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        if ( $tmp == $row['name'] )
        {
            if ( $row['facebook'] == 'Кредит на недвижимость' )
            {
                printf ("$('#mydiv11').html('" .$row['last_name']. " - ".$row['email']."');\r\n");
                if($row['img'] !="")
                    echo ("$('#kredit').html('<img width=\"340\" src=\"/db1/scripts/upload/" .$row['img']. "\"\ alt=\"Свяжитесь с нами\">');\r\n");
            }

            if ( $row['facebook'] == 'Срочный выкуп недвижимости')
            {
                printf ("$('#mydiv12').html('" .$row['last_name']. " - ".$row['email']."');");
                if($row['img'] !="")
                {
                    echo ("$('#srchvik').html('<img width=\"340\" src=\"/db1/scripts/upload/" .$row['img']. "\"\ alt=\"Свяжитесь с нами\">');\r\n");
                }
            }

            if ( $row['facebook'] == 'Страхование' )
            {
                printf ("$('#mydiv14').html('" .$row['last_name']. " - ".$row['email']."');");
                if($row['img'] !="")
                {
                    echo ("$('#kredits').html('<img width=\"340\" src=\"/db1/scripts/upload/" .$row['img']. "\"\ alt=\"Свяжитесь с нами\">');\r\n");
                }
            }

            if ( $row['facebook'] == 'Автокредит' )
                printf ("$('#mydiv10').html('" .$row['last_name']. " - ".$row['email']."');");

            if ( $row['facebook'] == 'Срочный выкуп авто' )
                printf ("$('#mydiv13').html('" .$row['last_name']. " - ".$row['email']."');");

            if ( $row['facebook'] == 'Специалист по недвижимости' )
            {
                if ( $i > 4 )
                    continue;

                printf ("$('#mydiv{$i}').html('" .$row['last_name']. " - ".$row['email']."');\r\n");
                echo ("$('#par{$i}').css('display', 'block');\r\n");
                if($row['img'] !="")
                    echo ("$('#mydivv{$i}').html('<img src=\"/db1/scripts/upload/" .$row['img']. "\"\ width=\"120\" height=\"78\" alt=\"Свяжитесь с нами\">');\r\n");
                if($row['textcomp'] !="")
                    echo ("$('#mydivvv{$i}').html('<li>" . implode( '</li><li>', explode( "\r\n", $row['textcomp'] ) ) . "</li>');\r\n");
                $i++;
            }

        }
    }
    endif;
    ?>
});
```

сам php запрос

```
        <?php
        require 'connect.php';

        if (isset($_POST['submit_add_user']))
        {
          $a_data  = $a_error  = [];
          $a_data['region_id']      = ( isset($_POST['region_id']) and is_string($_POST['region_id']) ) ? trim($_POST['region_id']) : '';
          $a_data['name']      = ( isset($_POST['name']) and is_string($_POST['name']) ) ? trim($_POST['name']) : '';
          $a_data['last_name'] = ( isset($_POST['last_name']) and is_string($_POST['last_name']) ) ? trim($_POST['last_name']) : '';
          $a_data['email']     = ( isset($_POST['email']) and is_string($_POST['email']) ) ? trim($_POST['email']) : '';
          $a_data['facebook']  = ( isset($_POST['facebook']) and is_string($_POST['facebook']) ) ? trim($_POST['facebook']) : '';
          $a_data['time']      = ( isset($_POST['time']) and is_string($_POST['time']) ) ? trim($_POST['time']) : '';
          $a_data['vk']        = ( isset($_POST['vk']) and is_string($_POST['vk']) ) ? trim($_POST['vk']) : '';
          $a_data['spec']      = ( isset($_POST['spec']) and is_string($_POST['spec']) ) ? trim($_POST['spec']) : '';
          $a_data['money']     = ( isset($_POST['money']) and is_string($_POST['money']) ) ? trim($_POST['money']) : '';
          $a_data['textcomp']  = ( isset($_POST['textcomp']) and is_string($_POST['textcomp']) ) ? trim($_POST['textcomp']) : '';
          $a_data['premich']  = ( isset($_POST['premich']) and is_string($_POST['premich']) ) ? trim($_POST['premich']) : '';
          $a_data['login']  = ( isset($_POST['login']) and is_string($_POST['login']) ) ? trim($_POST['login']) : '';
          $a_data['password']  = ( isset($_POST['password']) and is_string($_POST['password']) ) ? trim($_POST['password']) : '';
          $a_data['pochta']  = ( isset($_POST['pochta']) and is_string($_POST['pochta']) ) ? trim($_POST['pochta']) : '';
          $a_data['tarif']  = ( isset($_POST['tarif']) and is_string($_POST['tarif']) ) ? trim($_POST['tarif']) : '';
          $a_data['onoroff']  = ( isset($_POST['onoroff']) and is_string($_POST['onoroff']) ) ? trim($_POST['onoroff']) : '';
          $a_data['fiile']     = ( isset($_FILES['file']) ) ? $_FILES['file'] : [];


          //В этом месте напишете валидаторы, которые не будут разрешать писать в поля
          // что угодно. по этому примеру:
          //
//          if ( $a_data['email'] == '' )
//            $a_error['email'] = 'Вы не ввели e-mail';
//          else if ( false === filter_var( $a_data['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL ) )
//            $a_error['email'] = 'Вы ввели строку не похожую на e-mail';
//
          // потому что данная форма не обрабатывает ошибки и является уязвимой.
          // я понимаю, что это админка, но любые формы на сайте надо писать правильно
          // с защитой даже от себя пьяного

          if ($a_data['fiile'] == [])
            $a_error['fiile'] = 'Ошибка: Безопасность файла...';
          else if ( $a_data['fiile']['size'] == 0 ) {}
          else if ($a_data['fiile']['error'] != 0)
          {
            switch ($a_data['fiile']['error'])
            {
              // тексты ошибок при загрузке файла. их есть 7 штук. файлы не всегда
              // загружаются сразу и часто сбоят. если это не предусматривать, могут
              //быть проблемы
              case 1 : $a_error['fiile'] = 'Error #1';
                break;
              case 2 : $a_error['fiile'] = 'Error #2';
                break;
              case 3 : $a_error['fiile'] = 'Error #3';
                break;
              case 4 : $a_error['fiile'] = 'Error #4';
                break;
              case 6 : $a_error['fiile'] = 'Error #6';
                break;
              case 7 : $a_error['fiile'] = 'Error #7';
                break;
              case 8 : $a_error['fiile'] = 'Error #8';
                break;
            }
          }
          else
          {
            $a_ext = ['png', 'jpg'];

            if ( ! in_array(pathinfo($a_data['fiile']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION), $a_ext))
              $a_error['fiile'] = 'Некорректный формат картинки! Допустимый формат png, jpg'; // текст ошибки когда загружается левый файл

            if (getimagesize($a_data['fiile']['tmp_name']) === false)
              $a_error['fiile'] = 'BAD FILE'; // текст ошибки когда подменять файл картинкой
          }

          if ($a_error === [])
          {
            /**
             *  Это блок действия. Его надо выполнять тогда, когда к данным
             * которые Вы ожидаете получить нет притезний. если есть запись в
             * массив a_error это значит. что данные использовать нельзя, так как
             * в них есть хоть одна но ошибка
             */
            //новое имя изображения
            if ( $a_data['fiile']['size'] > 0 )
            {
                $apend      = date('YmdHis') . rand(100, 1000) . '.png';
                move_uploaded_file($a_data['fiile']['tmp_name'], "upload/{$apend}");
            }
            else
                $apend      ='';

            $insert_sql = "INSERT INTO `users`
              SET
              `region_id`       = '" . mysql_real_escape_string( $a_data['region_id'] ) . "',
              `name`       = '" . mysql_real_escape_string( $a_data['name'] ) . "',
              `last_name`  = '" . mysql_real_escape_string( $a_data['last_name'] ) . "',
              `email`      = '" . mysql_real_escape_string( $a_data['email'] ) . "',
              `facebook`   = '" . mysql_real_escape_string( $a_data['facebook'] ) . "',
              `time`       = '" . mysql_real_escape_string( $a_data['time'] ) . "',
              `vk`         = '" . mysql_real_escape_string( $a_data['vk'] ) . "',
              `spec`       = '" . mysql_real_escape_string( $a_data['spec'] ) . "',
              `money`      = '" . mysql_real_escape_string( $a_data['money'] ) . "',
              `textcomp`   = '" . mysql_real_escape_string( $a_data['textcomp'] ) . "',
              `premich`    = '" . mysql_real_escape_string( $a_data['premich'] ) . "',
              `login`      = '" . mysql_real_escape_string( $a_data['login'] ) . "',
              `password`   = '" . mysql_real_escape_string( $a_data['password'] ) . "',
              `pochta`     = '" . mysql_real_escape_string( $a_data['pochta'] ) . "',
              `tarif`      = '" . mysql_real_escape_string( $a_data['tarif'] ) . "',
              `onoroff`      = '" . mysql_real_escape_string( $a_data['onoroff'] ) . "',
              `img`        = '" . mysql_real_escape_string( $apend ) . "'";


            if ( mysql_query($insert_sql) )
            {
              if ( mysql_affected_rows() )
                echo "<script>alert('Партнер добавлен в базу!');window.location.href = '../all_users.php'</script>";
              else
                echo "<p>Партнер НЕ БЫЛ ДОБАВЛЕН!</p>";
            }
            else
              echo 'Запись не добавлена, так как база данных сайта не смогла ответить. Попробуйте позже.';
          }
          else
          {
            foreach ( $a_error as $key => $row )
              echo "В поле: {$row} найдена ошибка: {$row}";
          }
        }
        ?>
```

Comment: А во что Вы переделать хотите? Вам переформулировать вопрос надо.

Comment: Исправил вопрос

Comment: А что значить "не отображать на сайте"? Что бы его не видели другие юзеры, когда этот человек в сети?

Comment: просто сделать display:none

Comment: Не проще-ли, в самом `SQL` запросе это проверять?

Comment: добавил сам запрос

Comment: не стоит перезадавать вопрос [многократно](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/775803/213987).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы формулируете вопрос одновременно и на уровне бизнес-потребности ("не отображать пользователей") и одновременно просите подсказать с конкретной технической реализацией ("как поставить display:none"), проблемы я так понимаю от того, что вы не очень хорошо ориентируетесь в самом языке.

Почему я начал с описания потребности, а не сразу дал техническую реализацию? Потому что я сходу вижу три способа решить бизнес-потребность и ваша реализация не самая оптимальная.

Самый простой способ закрыть потребность – это просто пропустить строку.

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        if ( $tmp == $row['name'] )
        {
            if ( $row['onoroff'] == 1 )
                continue;

            if ( $row['facebook'] == 'Кредит на недвижимость' )
            {
```

У меня очень большие вопросы к тому, как у вас построен код (один подход, когда вы генерируете содержимое js-скрипта динамически из PHP чего стоит: здесь напрашивается ajax-запрос), но в сложившейся ситуации пожалуй, это будет самое элегантное решение, я рекомендую именно этот способ.

Второй вариант по степени элегантности – это отобрать нужных пользователей ещё на сервере, добавив условие в SQL-запрос:

```
$sql_select = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE onoroff = 0";
```

Это тот вариант, который вам предлагали в комментариях и которым я пошёл бы сам. Почему я ставлю его на второе место? Потому что мне показалось, что у вас какое-то недоверие и если вам дать только этот вариант ответа, то вы его не примете, а зря. Способ сильно экономит ресурсы сервера: не нужно даже загружать с SQL строки в оперативку, чтобы их потом не отбросить.

И только третий случай, который вы сами видите - это сделать display:none.
Мне очень сильно он не нравится, потому что я не понимаю, куда его воткнуть, там столько уже условий натыкано, что есть подозрение, что ещё через итерацию у вас этот код продублируется многократно и станет ещё сложнее читать.

Но вот вам набросок, как это сделать минимальными усилиями.

```
$hidder = ($row['onoroff'] == 1) ? " style='display:none;'" : "";
if($row['img'] !="")
    echo ("$('#mydivv{$i}').html('<img $hidder src=\"/db1/scripts/upload/" .$row['img']. "\"\ width=\"120\" height=\"78\" alt=\"Свяжитесь с нами\">');\r\n");
```

Здесь использован не if, а тернарный оператор, очень удобная штука. Можете заинлайнить его, но у вас там уже неразборчивая мешанина кода, поэтому я наоборот выносил расчёт отдельно – чтобы улучшить читаемость.

Comment: отлично но что не так, не записывается в бд          <label for="time">
     <i class="fa fa-clock-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> Выключить?:</label><br/>
          <input type="checkbox" <?php if ($a_data['onoroff']=='1') echo 'checked="checked"'; ?> name="onoroff" value="<?= ( isset( $a_data['onoroff'] ) ? $a_data['onoroff'] : '' ) ?>">
          <?= ( isset( $a_error['onoroff'] ) ? '<span style="color: red">'  . $a_error['onoroff'] . '</span><br />' : '' ) ?>